# Automatically tweet what I play on windows media player

Tags: windows-media-player

Is there a way to automatically tweet the music that I play on windows media player aside from the now playing plugin since it requires license for extended use.
Any other alternative music players that allows me to tweet the title of the music plus the artist will also do. Things like spotify, pandora, last.fm are not considered since they only work on selected countries.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Beats me. This could be solved with the media player API and some Perl code I guess. But this is SU, not SO. (Also: Twitter got some API limit I guess, so you can't just SPAM the whole feed with your songs...not to talk about those times when you start skipping between them...)

Comment: "aside from the now playing plugin since it requires license for extended use."  So you already have one, you just don't want to pay for it? What else have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not limited to just using Windows Media Player (as you seem to be willing to do), it appears that there's an excellent plugin for Winamp called (creatively) TwittAMP. It appears to be very flexible to post with and has an excellent step-by-step setup guide on their website.

Winamp overall is a very nice player if you've never used it, so I'd give it a try (and my recommendation).

TwittAMP website: http://twittamp.dev2.hu/